# Protest for my account suspension

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139942/the-biquadratic-character-of-2-mod-p-for-a-prime-of-the-form-p-4n1) about two month ago. Shortly after this, I got a moderator private message.
It says:

> We've noticed that you have a pattern of engaging in lengthy discussions in comments, frequently consisting of responses involving multiple, back-to-back posts. Extensive comment threads tend to be a distraction for other readers.
>
> In view of precedents on math.stackexchange.com, we are immediately suspending your account for a few days. We hope that you will take this time to reflect on the way you decide to interact with the MathOverflow community.

I believe that a MSE user's suspension should not be a reason for his suspension in MO.
As for the lengthy discussions in comments, I think they talk about the comments in [my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139942/the-biquadratic-character-of-2-mod-p-for-a-prime-of-the-form-p-4n1).

You can see that the discussion was triggered by a moderator's request that I post link to MSE meta questions which are relevant to my MSE account suspension.

Comment: Suspensions are not really up for debate and, moreover, the message you got with the suspensión is amply clear of the reasons behind it. On top of that, there is no reason why behaviour on MSE should not be taken into account here. In all, I can't see the point of this post except for reinforcing the points made by the mod in that message.

Comment: How many times now have you complained about this on meta?  It's getting annoying.  Please stop.

Comment: While I agree that OP's insistance can get annoying, I have to say that given the linked thread and me being unable to find any other recent long comment thread on main (was something deleted?) I've some sympathy for OP's surprise. He was greeted by an unjustified accusation (OP was active on MO before so it isn't clear he's using MO to circumvent any suspension, and even if so people's opinion on this is off-topic for main). Then, was encouraged by a moderator to provide details continuing on a/the meta debate, which were dilligently supplied, just to receive hostile comments by somebody.

Comment: @AndyPutman Do you think I should be silent even if I was suspended wrongly?
This is a democratic community, isn't it?

Comment: More generally, as in various cases of so-called "problematic" users a main problem in my opinion is with "mainstream users" (for lack of a better word) that for some reason [pseudo-psychological commentary surpressed] provoke the user.

Comment: @quid: I don't know how well versed you are in the history of this user's behavior. But my experience tells me that "more generally" does not (in general) apply.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I feel I am somewhat familiar with the math.SE history related to this, and for the more recent one [specfically for the relevant time span in this case, so around august] I feel rather well-informed (and oberserved the behavior I described, too). Maybe that I said 'a main problem' is too strong, but it is at least part of the problems, and also a problem, one that does not get address much (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @Makoto Kato: I'm sorry for my rudeness, but I would like to suggest that you not protest the suspension. Instead use the suspension as an opportunity to learn how to use this site more productively! There was a problem, and you've received a gift of a few days to think things over and to overcome the problem. It's a learning opportunity, not a punishment :-) . Limit yourself to 2-3 comments per comment thread at most, for instance, and you'll find yourself better received, and you'll get more out of the site.

Comment: @quid To answer the question in your first comment, I can confirm that *a lot* was deleted. Whole posts were deleted, and in posts that remained alive there were a lot of comments deleted by mods (and some by the owners as well). So there is some history that you (even with your detailed knowledge of MO and meta, which I've always found impressive) might not be able to see -- I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @ToddTrimble thanks for letting me know, this explains it, I assume. (I'd still maintain the "more generally" in abstract, but this is a bit off-topic here.)

Comment: @MakotoKato : I will not respond further, but given that no one but you seems to think that your suspension was unjust, you should probably rethink your position here.  And wasting everyone's time by whining about it over and over again is not going to help you.

Comment: A recent question on this topic: [Is there any process to appeal bans?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5030)

Answer (score 4):

In the case of an unjust suspension (or at least what a user considers to be an unjust suspension), it seems that better way than to bring this up on meta would be contact the SE team using the [contact form](https://mathoverflow.net/contact) or by writing an email to team@stackexchange.com.

See, for example,  an answer to the meta.SO question: [Where I can complain about an unfair account suspension?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165359/where-i-can-complain-about-an-unfair-account-suspension/165360#165360). This solution was also suggested to you in a [similar discussion on meta.MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11158/having-been-flagged-many-times-can-be-a-reason-for-the-suspension#comment42293_11160).

EDIT: As François G. Dorais points out in [his comment below](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1066/protest-for-my-account-suspension#comment4779_1068), another way to dispute a suspension is to [contact the MathOverflow moderators](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/833/who-are-the-mathoverflow-moderators).

Comment: MO might be a special case, though. IIRC, there was an agreement before the move SE will not intervene with site's moderation except in somehow urgent cases (say, massive spam attack or something like this).

Comment: @quid I was aware that MO has some kind of special status about some things, but I did not know the details; so I thought that account suspensions are handled similarly as for other sites.

Comment: I will remove my answer if it is indeed incorrect. (For example, if the quid's comment is confirmed by some of MO mods or if someone points out the part of [migration agreement](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9bqmDNwzTjkLWxuR21FNHJWSXM/edit?usp=sharing) or some other agreement which regulates this.)

Comment: This is not an inappropriate way to file a complaint. Another is to contact the MathOverflow moderators directly - http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/833/who-are-the-mathoverflow-moderators

Comment: I think this deserves public attention.
Not eveybody gets suspension, but I think it's meaningful that the users know the moderators' mind set.

Comment: I misread Francois's comment above as "not an appropriate" instead of "not an inappropriate" ...

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche You were [not the only one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11766411#11766411).