# Is there any process to appeal suspensions?

Tags: support, feature-request, specific-user, account-suspension

Does mathoverflow have any procedure for appealing suspensions?

I'm asking because I was banned for a week (I believe unjustly) due to rude behavior.

**Question:** What recourse is there if I feel I was banned unjustly?

If anyone's curious, I believe the damning event was where a user named 'tarotquestion' posted something about tarot cards and I, naturally, commented 'We got one boys, bring the handcuffs.' The question was deleted right after I was banned.
There were two similar events prior to this wherein the question was either closed or deleted after I made my investigation.

**Edit:** Thanks for your answers. Especially Tim Campion's clarification on requisite tone and Martin Sleziak's links to support features (which probably would not have resulted in an overturn of this suspension) and to Makoto's old post. Seeing these answers and links, I definitely think it is a good idea (for the benefit of outsiders and newcomers) to document/clarify what your community sees as acceptable/unacceptable behaviour.

P.S. Perhaps I should add that I also made a stern face '~.~' at a HW poster in my role as HWPolice.

Comment: [Here's the relevant meta SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316631/what-can-i-do-to-lift-or-reduce-a-suspension) on appealing suspensions.

Comment: Was this your first offence? Did you get a warning before the ban?

Comment: No warning, first offense. But it's ok, I made a separate account to discuss mathematics in case this one gets banned.

Comment: @HWPolice It is not acceptable to create a second account to circumvent a suspension. Doing so is grounds for escalating suspensions, and quite frankly is a great way to annoy the moderators.

Comment: Just a minor terminological nitpicking concerning the title. On the Stack Exchange platform, the word ban is more often used for [question/answer ban](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/post-ban/info) - this is done automatically by the software, without any involvement of moderators. What you mean is called [suspension](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/account-suspension/info). (OTOH I suppose that every body understood.)

Comment: A link to an older question: [Protest for my account suspension](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1066).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here again is the relevant meta SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316631/what-can-i-do-to-lift-or-reduce-a-suspension) on appealing suspensions.

Here is some general advice for users who have been suspended.

It's natural, when being disciplined, to feel defensive, or to feel wronged.

But remember that one purpose of the suspension is to give you time to reflect on your behavior, and to try to understand how you can change your behavior to better conform to the norms of the community you've been suspended from.

Some types of behavior which are acceptable on other parts of the internet are not acceptable here on MO. Our standards of behavior are closer in spirit to the standards of a seminar room or perhaps a departmental lounge. This is a professional environment, and users are expected to behave professionally.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I will continue asking suspicious users if they have posted HW. Would you take issue with that?

Comment: Generally if a question is a homework question, one or both of the following conditions also holds: (1) it is obvious that it is a homework question / (2) it is obvious that the question is not suitable for MO on the grounds of its _content_ alone. In neither case is it necessary to "confront" the user about posting a homework question. It's generally more appropriate to simply vote to close, and perhaps leave a friendly note pointing out that homework questions are off-topic here. A tone of being the "homework police" is not really appropriate on MO.

Comment: Ok, perhaps in the future then. With a friendlier name and tone...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, there is no rule against opening a meta post to discuss your own ban and defending yourself; especially if you wish to draw the attention of the community to a ban that you find unjust.

Comment: Agreed, but before deciding that your ban is unjust, I hope you will, in Tim's words, reflect on your behavior, and to try to understand how you can change your behavior to better conform to the norms of the community you've been suspended from.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Campion already pointed out the FAQ post: [What can I do to lift or reduce a suspension?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316631) I will add also link to another answer on Meta Stack Exchange: [Where I can complain about an unfair account suspension?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165359#165360)

Apart from replying to the moderator message, you can also use [the contact form](https://mathoverflow.net/contact) to contact Stack Exchange Team. On MathOverflow you have also an option to [contact the MO moderators](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/833/who-are-the-mathoverflow-moderators/834#834) using email. (This is specific for MO, other sites in the Stack Exchange network do not have such option.) In an older discussion it was [mentioned by a MO moderator](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1066/protest-for-my-account-suspension/1068#1068) that this is a possibility how to object to a suspension.

If you use the first option, you're communicated with the Stack Exchange employees. The second option means contacting directly the MathOverflow moderators.

Comment: I am not really sure why the downvote - I have just mentioned a solution which was endorsed by one of MO moderators in a previous discussion about this issue.