# Mugs, Stickers And Shirts - Now With 100% More MathOverflow!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The MathOverflow Foundation has given Stack Exchange permission to print and ship (at our expense) free gifts for outstanding users of the site that want them, or that will be attending conferences where the items can be used to help promote the site. I'm very pleased to announce the immediate availability of the following items:

MathOverflow mugs for your favorite tasty beverage:

[image: Mugs]

MathOverflow shirts, because some stores require you to wear shirts:

[image: Shirts]

MathOverflow stickers, because blank spaces are boring:

[image]

How do I get some of these wonderful items, you ask? It's simple, but varies depending on why you want them.

#### For Conferences Or Events

Please take a moment and fill out [the following form](http://s.tk/swagrequest), and we'll get in touch with you through the email address that you provide. Generally, we just need some evidence that the conference is something legitimate, and be certain that you understand that the items must be provided completely free of charge. Give us *as much advanced notice as possible*, preferably 30 days or more.

#### I use the site, and would just like a mug, please!

Normally, the system contacts users once they reach certain reputation thresholds and offers them some items. We're not doing that here, because that's not a very good mechanism for this community - many here would rather not *have* rep.

If you're an established user that has:

- Been a member in good standing for at least six months
- Have *at least* several posts with a score above 3
- A desire for stuff

Then simply fill out [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1s_jlSeQbTSwmWm81B1PKqggIsokH9vmZMJKSoBqtjUo/viewform?usp=send_form), and allow six to eight weeks for delivery. I'm trying to keep the criteria as *loose* as I possibly can, I just want to make sure that folks receiving this stuff have actually made (and will hopefully continue to make) valuable contributions to this site, without relying on your level of reputation. Exceptions can be made on advice from your moderators.

You can request any (or all) of the items above, as well as some extra stickers from other sites that you might use.

#### I'm a MathOverflow moderator, and I'd like you to send something to {user}

Contact me directly via email (it's in my profile) to let me know, and I'll take care of it.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask in the comments below. I think these turned out *very* nicely, and I hope you're as excited as we are!

**Update**

I'll be allowing a few more days to compile responses from folks so we can get as many as possible out in one swoop, these will be shipped near the end of this week.

***Second Update***

What we had in stock went for sponsorship of ICM 2014, which came together at the very last minute. We should have more printed and available in the next few days, at which point we'll have this all shipped out. Sorry for the delay all, it really was a last-minute opportunity or I would have waited to post this.

Comment: I would appreciate commentary from MathOverflow Foundation reps (moderators as well) on the following likely (better than 30% chance) scenario: I would be attending ICM in Seoul in mid August, and am willing to devote some time to promoting MathOverflow.  How much swag to order, and how to use it?  There are also logistic issues, as well as some political issues.  For example, is MO 1.0 style publicity favored over MO 2.0 style?  Does MOF have a public relations guide for me to follow?  Do I pass out mugs informally, or whip out my smart phone and give a 30 second demo before they get a mug?

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: Please send an email to the moderators -http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/833/who-are-the-mathoverflow-moderators

Comment: I have the MSE mug, and it is wunderbar! (Although there was an immediate discoloration inside the mug; but nothing I actually cared about.)

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger The mods can help you with most of that. When I give talks promoting our sites, I try to make sure everyone that wants something at least gets some stickers, and I reserve the bigger prizes (shirts / mugs) for folks that actively participate with questions about the presentation or talk I'm giving - works out well. As for the quantity, we'll hook you up with enough to satisfy about 100 attendees (stickers), with 20 or so also getting mugs or shirts. Depends on the event, can be more.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe we changed mugs, you should be able to put a double shot of espresso in these without discoloration, but don't let coffee / tea sit in them overnight. You know, since I have the ability, I should actually _send myself_ one of our own SO mugs (same brand) and see :P I'll get on that today.

Comment: @Tim: We are very prone to leaving dishes for a couple of days. Which is how the last mug got stained. Also drinking espresso from such mug is weird.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, an Americano starts out with a shot or two (which didn't stain the mug). But I am going to get some mugs and do some science, as they're our most sought after item when we print them for sites.

Comment: @Tim: I stopped diluting my coffee with excessive amounts of water. When the water stop being dark, I stop the machine. I mean, what's next? Taking a Glen Livet 25 and adding a glass of water to a shot? :-(

Comment: @Tim, I will check with the mods.  Thanks for the data point.

Comment: I got a math.stackexange mug a while back.  Any thought on producing a dark-colored mug ... coffee & tea stains invisible ...

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I'm going to ask our supplier. Incidentally, +100 for that sudden onslaught of common sense that seemed to escape the rest of us (well, namely, me :P)

Comment: @Tim: I would have expected you to be able and actually have Gerald Edgar's comment with +100. Also, please let me know when you do that sciency part on the mugs! I'm interested in the results.

Comment: Protip: You can get rid of staining (from tea; I don't know about coffee) by letting it soak in vinegar overnight, then scrubbing vigorously.

Comment: Oh, OK. I now understand why the old meta.MO used to be called 'tea'.

Comment: I filled out the form linked (about least 9 weeks ago). Is it possible to get confirmation that items are on their way?

Comment: Like David, I filled out the form shortly after this question was posted and haven't heard anything since.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Have your mugs, stickers and shirts reached you already?

Comment: @J.H.S. no (or at least, not as of yesterday, I haven't checked today). Scott Morrison told me via email that a lot of the stock was sent to the ICM, so requests were delayed somewhat.

Comment: @TimPost - any news on shipments? See the preceding comments.

Comment: All - updated the post. All that we had in stock went to sponsor / represent MO at ICM 2014, at the last minute (we didn't know we'd have the opportunity), so all we had in stock was diverted. More is being printed, should be ready shortly, and we'll have the warehouse send all of this out from that batch, then print more so we have some in stock. Sorry about the chaos, it just worked out the way that it did.

Comment: @TimPost what's ICS 2014? Google shows me _International Continence Society_, _International Carbohydrate Symposium_, _Interdisciplinary Cerebrovascular Symposium_ and _International Conference on Supercomputing_. One of these things is not like the other, but I can't tell if I've found what you're referring to or not :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a typo for ICM.

Comment: It is ICM, I was only on my sixth espresso, sorry about that!

Comment: Tim, did you make sciency experiments about mug stains? Also, will there be black mugs at some point? (I'd be happy to get one of these...)

Comment: What sort of shipping times are expected? I will be moving in just over a month, so if I need to change my address somewhere, it would be good to know.

Comment: @TimPost Since my move is rapidly approaching, I would appreciate an update on where I would need to change my address.

Comment: @TimPost: Has the stuff been sent already?

Comment: Ah, but with dark cups, @GeraldEdgar, you can't judge how much milk to add to your tea.

Comment: Will you be sending the free stuff to other countries?  I'm from the Philippines, I filled up the form last year and I haven't received anything yet.

Comment: I never got the swag I requested. Had it not been offered I wouldn't feel the lack. Was a second batch ever printed?

Comment: @TimPost Is it too late to get one?

Answer (score 15):

### The swag is here!

The re-order shipment is now in stock and that information we've been holding for over a year now has been sent off to our warehouse so the orders can now be processed. Everything will be shipped shortly and should start arriving at your doorsteps (or wherever you get your mail) over the coming weeks. Enjoy!

Comment: So are you the new lord of swag? (At least I think I've heard that Tim Post gave up his crown.)

Comment: Can new swagophiles make new swag requests?

Comment: I got my swag---thanks a lot! The caviar is fantastic.

Comment: Excellent. I just received mine. Thank you!

Comment: Mine just arrived.  Thank you.

Comment: Just got mine too, thanks!

Comment: Chiming in with thanks

Comment: Got mine in Australia, thanks!

Comment: Got mine (in the Philippines) yesterday!  Thanks!

Comment: @Joel: Can you tell me when it was that your parcel was posted? Thank you very much!

Comment: @J.H.S. It seems that my package was sent on [October 21, 2015](https://joelreyesnoche.wordpress.com/2015/10/28/gift-from-mathoverflow/).

Comment: I also received it. Fantastic!

Answer (score 10):

I'm adding this as an answer, rather than a comment, to bump the question.

I haven't received my swag yet, despite it being about 14 months later.

I notice Joel Reyes Noche and Aaron Meyerowitz mentioned this in comments above a couple of months ago with no response.

**EDIT:** I emailed Tim Post and he got back to me to say that he will get the ball rolling later today.

Comment: Likewise........

Comment: Paging @TimPost

Comment: It could be more efficient to write an email to Tim Post (see his profile for it) or perhaps to the SE team via "Contact Us" for instance. In any case your last comment has essentially no effect as it will not notify. I vaguely recall that Tim Post now has a different role in SE, which might explain the delay.

Comment: @quid Post's profile at meta.stackechange still says community involvement, so I assumed this was a relevant position. But you are right regarding email SE directly, which will get the attention of the correct people.

Comment: In his profile he says that he is "Director of Stack Overflow Communities;" note it says "Overflow" not "Exchange" (in contrast to plenty others). I believe he now is focused on the SO sites only, trying to get more different language sites running. But this is a bit tangential speculation.

Comment: Thanks for your initiative on this matter. I hope those interested will soon receive their goods. And then I hope for some photos of the fellow MOers with the new gear. :-)

Comment: There are actually a few photos of such members on the ICM2014 website.  For the mere cost of an (authenticated) photo of yourself (with your face), I'll be happy to comb the site and send you links.  Gerhard "Quite Willing To Scratch Backs" Paseman, 2015.09.02

Comment: Gerhard, you are a card!

Comment: Hey everyone. Sorry about the delay. We are submitting orders now to get everything we need restocked, and will get everything shipped out to you guys whenever that stuff reaches our warehouse. I don't have an exact timeline, but I'll follow up here again once we get the stuff in.

Comment: @animuson What about possible address changes?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If you (or anyone else) need to update your address, send shoot me an email (my display name @stackoverflow.com) with your new details and I'll update it in the file.

Comment: @animuson did you want to update the OP, so that it bumps, and people can see an official SE response?