# Can I get a promotion?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

What activities, if any, are currently being done to promote MO? Have opinions changed from two years ago with [this post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/945/is-there-any-way-to-invite-more-experts-active-researchers-from-various-subjec)?

Comment: "Has opinion changed from two years ago with this post?" What *opinion* do you refer to? There are completely contradictory opinions voiced there.

Comment: @quid Of course you are correct and it is edited. I am mostly wondering if anything much has been done since then.

Comment: A question I would ask based on the 2-year old question is : What areas/aspects of mathematics are underrepresented on MO?

Comment: @GilKalai Fair enough. Shall I trim off the second question and you ask this question? I would be very interested in the answers.

Comment: no need to trim off anything, but I can indeed ask it.

Answer (score 6):

I have done some independent efforts to promote MathOverflow, primarily by talking to small groups, including groups both at ICM2010 and ICM2014.  In addition to some conference members (most notably Mariano Suarez-Alvarez and Charles Siegel), I was aided by StackExchange and Tim Post in particular, who helped with swag, to distribute at ICM2014.

The MathOverflow foundation was also supportive of my efforts, and is looking for additional ideas and volunteers.  You can contact them through moderation email moderators@mathoverflow.net.  You can also contact me using my email address provided in [MathOverflow @ ICM2014 : We Want You!](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1830/), or https://mathoverflow.net/users/3206 or https://mathoverflow.net/users/3402 .

While I and others are considering several possibilities, it will come down to getting the right word out, and providing the right service.  MathOverflow has grown reasonably well because of the service it offers and the word-of-mouth provided by its community.  In my opinion, to ensure continued growth, it will need to consider offering new services to attract more members, while maintaining the quality content that comes from a knowledgeable user base and ceaseless community moderation.

I look forward to hearing your ideas.

Gerhard "Not Community Relations Manager, Yet" Paseman, 2015.08.31

Comment: First off, thank you for your efforts. Have you considered doing this at a national level (AMS, CMS, other countries, etc.)? Do you have any additional services in mind?

Comment: @ChrisRamsey, short answers: yes and yes.  And you're welcome.  There is a volunteer position being formed, which I title "Community Relations Czar" (title may be changed), which is more likely to be shared among people.  Even if you want to be involved but not at a management level, let the moderators know and they will put us in touch with one another as appropriate.  I am willing to discuss my ideas with you, but not in comment fields or meta postings at this stage.  Gerhard "'Despot For The People'?  Nah." Paseman, 2015.09.02

Comment: A shared title is more like a triumvir, less like a czar.