# Why does this figure do not appear?

Tags: discussion, support, images

I  add a  Picture "GaussBonnet with Jpeg format to  the  following  question but it does  not  work.

[(Some possible obstructions to ) Limit cycles as closed geodesics(3)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302009/some-possible-obstructions-to-limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesics3)

Can one help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: I have [edited your post](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/302009/revisions), maybe it has the form you wanted to achieve. (And maybe not, but at least some pictures are displayed now.) So maybe you might add a link to [revision where it did not work](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/302009/7) and also [the source](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/b7dec4cc-83d9-476e-bb90-dcfac619bcac/view-source) of that revision - so that the question on meta still illustrates what is (was?) the problem.

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Thank  you  very  much  for  your  edit.  When  I  clique on the picture, it  does  not  appear. In your  computer, does the picture  appear  automatically? Can you see this picture?

Comment: BTW the two pictures look the same to me. (Although the links are different - in the current revision https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxQiy.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxaM7.jpg ) Did I miss some difference?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. Are you saying that after my edit you still do not see the pictures?

Comment: @MartinSleziak  I tried  both with  computer  and  my Phone. when I clique on the link "GaussBonnet"  It try to enter i.stack.Imgur.com/....   but it fail. any Way thank you for  your  help. Yes  the  two picture are the same. I  added  the  second  one  because  the  first one  did not  work. Now, according to your  comment I realize that the  problem is mine(by my  phone  and  computer).

Comment: Sometimes clearing the browser cache works.  Gerhard "And Sometimes It Doesn't Work" Paseman, 2018.06.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman  Yes, I see. thank you. Now my problem is  resolved.I can see the picture.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to give some advice since it is not clear what went wrong. The OP has confirmed in the meantime that now the images are visible in the post. As you can see in [the revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/302009/revisions), all I did was adding the missing "!".

If a picture is uploaded through the editor, the Stack Exchange software should take care of the correct syntax for the picture. Of course, it is possible that when editing the post something goes wrong. Solution is either to upload picture again or try to edit the post into correct syntax.

As you can see in the section on images in the [Markdown help](https://mathoverflow.net/editing-help), it is possible to use HTML image syntax. Markdown syntax for images can be `![text](url)` or `![text][1]` where `[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3C50.png) refers to link.

Example: `![MathOveflow logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3C50.png)` [image: MathOveflow logo]

The same can be obtained by

```
![MathOveflow logo][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3C50.png
```

[image: MathOveflow logo]

However, as already mentioned, probably the best strategy is to upload pictures through the editor and leave it up to the software that the correct syntax for inclusion of the pictures is used.

Some relevant links:

- [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491)

The picture used in the example is taken from: [Mugs, Stickers And Shirts - Now With 100% More MathOverflow!](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1748).

Comment: Can perhaps somebody confirm whether they see the pictures in the linked question on the main? After the most recent comments from the OP I am rather unsure what's going on.

Comment: Now I  can see the picture in my  computer. Sorry  for  my  several comments  and  thanks  for  your  help.