# Is it possible to find out why a comment was deleted?

Tags: support, comments, moderation, deletions

I had a comment at [How do you generate math figures for academic papers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/411870/how-do-you-generate-math-figures-for-academic-papers) asking whether the question was a duplicate.  (Carlo Beenakker is responding to it in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/411870/how-do-you-generate-math-figures-for-academic-papers#comment1055365_411870).)  Since the comment is no longer there, and since I did not delete it, I assume that it was deleted in response to moderator flags.  I have no objection to the deletion—the comment is largely superseded by Carlo Beenakker's—but, if it was in some way inappropriate, then I would like to know so that I can avoid further inappropriate behaviour.  Is it possible to find out what happened?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of question only a moderator can answer. I know the moderators read meta, but maybe quicker to contact them directly?

Comment: Is it possible that the comment was deleted automatically by the system? This is a rather old post, the behavior might have changed since then: [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141414#195654). According to that post, at the time it worked like this: "Any comment that contains the word "duplicate" and a link to another question is deleted when a question is closed. "

Comment: @GerryMyerson I will just add that every question on meta automatically makes a notification in the moderator inbox (as [confirmed by Todd Trimble](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46397751#46397751)). When you suggested to contact the moderator directly, did you mean [the email address moderators@mathoverflow.net](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/833/who-are-the-mathoverflow-moderators/834#834)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak, [that](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5196/is-it-possible-to-find-out-why-a-comment-was-deleted#comment26651_5196) suggestion makes sense, but I'm not sure it applies—the post isn't closed, and my comment literally just *asked* whether it was a duplicate; I didn't supply a link because I couldn't find one.  But maybe it was closed and re-opened?

Comment: I deleted that comment in response to a 'no longer needed' flag, as it did not contain much concrete information (in contrast to Carlo Beenakker's response). Thus, to answer your question -- the comment was in no way inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks, @StefanKohl!  Can you leave [that](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5196/is-it-possible-to-find-out-why-a-comment-was-deleted#comment26654_5196) as an answer so I can mark it accepted, or should I just close this question?

Comment: @Martin, I might have been thinking of math.stackexchange, where there is a chatroom for bringing things to the attention of moderators. Or, flagging a random post for moderator attention.

Comment: @LSpice You are welcome! -- Done.

Comment: @LSpice The post actually was [closed and then reopened](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/411870/revisions). So I thought that your comment might have been deleted when together with the closure. But since you say that your comment did not contain any link, the mechanism I described above clearly does not apply. (As a side note, would maybe ([meta-tag:deletions]) be suitable here as a tag?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I deleted that comment in response to a 'no longer needed' flag, as it did not contain much concrete information (in contrast to Carlo Beenakker's response). Thus, to answer your question -- the comment was in no way inappropriate.